# Seeking excel formula based on multiple criteria using a key

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have asked three developers and one VBA guru on my team who have no idea how to proceed with the following inquiry:

I have a KEY that has outlined several groups (the picture is only showing two).  These groups have different AUX definitions.  Productive AUX hours are indicated by a "W".

In my Clerk Data tab, I have imported daily data based on the various groups.  The snapshot shows an example of group 1 vs group 2 data.

I am looking for a formula to put into column O that will match the Group in column N to Column A in the key.  If it matches, then I want it to add up the aux fields based on if there is "W" populated.

If I were to manually calculate this, O30 would equal 15.4 hours.

In O31, it would be 5.75 hours.

Is a single formula possible in this scenario?

[image: data]

Comment: Showing some example outputs usually helps.

Comment: I thought I had attached the picture in the link above?

Comment: Is your output column not column O on the photo? If so, you are only showing inputs as the output column is blank. Sorry if I am misreading something! Plz clarify if I am :)

Comment: Yes, I am only showing inputs.  I am trying to figure out how to sum the various AUX codes based on if the AUX Key (bottom half of the image) has a "W" in the field.

Comment: So, in O30, if I were to manually calculate it, I would have 15.4;

Comment: In O31, it would be 5.93

Comment: Thank you! Plz add that to your question for others to see

Comment: If I understand your approach, I get 5.75 for O31 using the key for Group 1.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh sorry, yep!  5.75!  I added 0.2 instead of 0.02 from field Aux 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sums the values based on your key. This assumes that you keys are stored in a sheet named `Key`.

`=SUMIF(OFFSET(Key!$B$1:$K$1,MATCH(N30,Key!A:A,0)-1,0),"W",C30:L30)`

`SUMIF` takes `(range, criteria, sum_range)` where the range and sum_range have to be the same size.  It will sum the values in sum_range, `C30:L30`, if the equivalent cell in range matches the criteria, that is equals `W`.

range is `OFFSET(Key!$B$1:$K$1,MATCH(N30,Key!A:A,0)-1,0)`.

`OFFSET` takes `(reference, rows, cols)` where the reference is `Key!$B$1:$K$1`, which will be offset by the number of rows from `MATCH(N30,Key!A:A,0)-1`.

`MATCH` takes `(lookup_value, lookup_array, match_type)` which will find the row that matches your Group #, `N30`, in the range, `Key!A:A`.  match_type set to zero means it will look for an exact match.

Comment: Rey!  Thank you!  I think that's where I was caught up, I don't know much about OFFSET.  I'll read more about it tonight but thank you for all your help!  The formula worked great!

Comment: Glad to help. If this works for you, please mark as answered to clear it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

=SUMIF(Sheet2!B2:K2,"W",Sheet1!C31:L31)